# Vuejs Vuetify data table issue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify Data table with headers and item slots. Now i have a method setup which is supposed to toggle the checkboxes `toggleAll` and it seems to be partially working in terms that the rows get selected but the checkboxes do not get checkmarked. Now the `v-checkbox` has an `input-value` prop which handles the model but when i set a `v-model` and `value` prop, that's when the the checkboxes won't get checkmarked.

Here is a partially working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bartik-m0cq7?file=/src/store.js). You'll see that right now i am only able to select one checkbox and all the others don't get selected.

Here is my code:-

btw i am on Vuetify 1.5

This is my Table.vue File:-

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="getTableHeaders"
      :items="getDesserts"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:headers="props">
        <tr>
          <th class="checkbox">
            <v-checkbox
              hide-details
              primary
              :input-value="props.all"
              :indeterminate="props.indeterminate"
              @click.stop="toggleAll"
            />
          </th>
          <th
            v-for="(header,i) in props.headers"
            :key="`${i}`"
            class="font-weight-bold"
          >
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
          <td>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="selectRow"
              :value="props.item.value"
              :input-value="props.selected"
              primary
              hide-details
            ></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import {  mapGetters } from 'vuex';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selected: []
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            getTableHeaders: 'getTableHeaders',
            getDesserts: 'getDesserts',
            getSelectedRow: 'getSelectedRow'
        }),
        selectRow:{
          get() {
            return this.getSelectedRow;
          },
          set(val) {
            this.$store.commit('setSelectedRow', val)
          }
        }
    },
     methods: {
        toggleAll () {
           if (this.selected.length) this.selected = []
           else this.selected = this.desserts.slice()
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my Vuex Store :-

```
state: {
    selectedRow: [],
    headers: [
      { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',align: 'left',value: 'name'},
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        value: 'yogurt'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        value: 'sandwich'
      },
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getSelectedRow: state => state.selectedRow,
    getTableHeaders: state => state.headers,
    getDesserts: state => state.desserts
  },
  mutations: {
    setSelectedRow(state, payload) {
      state.selectedRow = payload;
    }
  },
```

Now the `toggleAll` seem to be setting the selected but for some reason are not getting checked. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн hello palash, trying to get that setup but haven't used code sandbox so trying to find my way through it lol.

Comment: You can try any other online code editor like codepen, jsfiddle, etc., whichever you use the most for sharing demos.

Comment: idk how to import vuex in codepen tbh.

Comment: @palaѕн check this fiddle. it's a partially working fiddle, code sandbox is not at all fun. https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bartik-m0cq7?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1767-1778

Comment: @palaѕн you'll see that i am not able to select all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your table template could be much simpler. Vuetify will actually produce the correct header for you without your having to specify a template for it. Your JavaScript could be **much** simpler, as well:

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-key="name"
    select-all
  >
    <template #items="props">
      <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
        <td>
          <v-checkbox
            :input-value="props.selected"
            primary
            hide-details
          ></v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-center">
          {{ props.item.calories }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-xs-center">
          {{ props.item.fat }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'MyVuexDataTable',
    computed: {
      ...mapState(['desserts', 'headers']),
      selected: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.selected
        },
        set (selected) {
          this.$store.dispatch('setSelected', selected)
        },
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

You also don't have to write your own function to do the toggling. Vuetify will handle that for you. As for the store, what you had is mostly fine, except you need to be careful when mutating objects and arrays. Vue's reactivity system won't react to changes of properties so it's best to use [the built-in `Vue.set()` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

```js
const SET_SELECTED = 'SET_SELECTED' // mutation type
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    selected: [],
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%',
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%',
      },
    ],
    headers: [
      { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', align: 'left',value: 'name'},
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    ],
  },
  actions: {
    setSelected ({ commit }, selected) {
      commit(SET_SELECTED, selected)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    [SET_SELECTED] (state, selected) {
      Vue.set(state, 'selected', [...selected])
    }
  },
})
```

[Here's a codepen with a fully working example](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/eYpvQva). It's slightly different than you'll use in your project because it all runs in the browser and there is no webpack build system.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me.
Header checkbox html code.

```
<v-simple-checkbox
    :value="selected.length == records.length"
    :indeterminate="selected.length>0 && selected.length<records.length"
    :ripple="false"
    @click="toggleSelectAll"
   ></v-simple-checkbox>
```

Toggle All function.

```
toggleSelectAll() {
    if (this.selected.length < this.records.length)
        this.selected = this.records;
    else this.selected = [];
}
```